# How do I receive an ng-click event behind a md-backdrop in Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a context menu that pops up in my Angular Material website.  When the md-menu shows, an md-backdrop is automatically created.  When I click outside of the md-menu the md-backdrop is clicked and the md-menu is closed.

I want to actually receive that ng-click.  For example, if I have an md-button on my webpage and a md-menu were to pop up, if I click the md-button the button does not fire because I'm clicking the md-backdrop.  I essentially have to click twice, once to close the md-menu and again to actually click the button.

I want to know if I can propagate this click beyond the md-backdrop and receive it on the md-button.  Otherwise I want to know how to disable the md-backdrop completely.

Comment: You can trigger click event of md-button from event handler of md-backdrop if you need

Comment: @JahirulIslamBhuiyan It's hard to know whether the md-button was clicked or not.  I don't want to assume that if someone is clicking the md-backdrop they are clicking my md-button as there are multiple buttons in different positions.  I can use the event handler of the md-backdrop which will give me a click event with a x and y position but is there an elegant way to use that information to tell if the user actually clicked the button? Is the only way to search through the x,y,and size info of each button and check if the x,y event click on the md-backdrop is inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by altering the z-index value of the md-backdrop.  I had to edit the css class which referred to the md-backdrop and set the z-index to a lower number than the md-button I wanted pressed.